# Groovy markup builder replace the root

Tags: xml, groovy, root, markupbuilder

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

class XmlTest {
    static void main(def args) {
        def XmlTest s = new XmlTest()
        s.xmlTest()
    }

    def xmlTest() {
        def xml = new MarkupBuilder()
        xml.root{
            response(this.xmlClosure())
        }
    }

    def xmlClosure() {
        return {x("y")}
    }
}
```

The expected output is `<x>y</x>`
I cannot modify the closure. I need to convert the closure to a XML document without adding any nodes.

Comment: The output i received it is <root>
  <response>
    <x>y</x>
  </response>
</root>

Comment: Please add additional details to the question itself, not as comments.

Comment: I guess you could do 'return new MarkupBuilder().x("y")' and skip the xmlClosure method all together, but that's not what you're after, right? Is your question "How can I strip the <root>-element?", or am I way out?

Comment: yes you are right silverbeak. i cannot modify the closure. The actual closure is complex with nested elements and arrays. I need a way to strip the root element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help, but if you have more element types than just "x" you probably should expand on it a bit. By letting the builder write to a writer, you can take control of the result in a more controlled manner. Then, using the writer, you can extract the elements you want using a StreamingMarkupBuilder.

It's a very roundabout way, and for very large XML structures, it may not be very efficient.

I also took the liberty to omit the "response" element, as I didn't see that it made any sense. Feel free to put it back if you absolutely need it.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

class XmlTest {
    static void main(def args) {
        def sw = new StringWriter()
        println new XmlTest().xmlTest(sw)
    }

    def xmlTest(writer) {
        def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)        
        builder.root(xmlClosure())

        def text = new XmlSlurper().parseText(writer.toString())

        def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
        def result = outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield text.x }
        return result
    }

    def xmlClosure() {
        return {x("y")}
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks it worked. My only concern, we are re-parsing the xml again to remove the node. The closure takes mkp as a parameter. I am not able to specify mkp as parameter to xmlClosure()